# Enabling view state is not working with controls in web part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

**What I have?**

I have a simple web part which has a `Table`. The table has two controls, a `TextBox` and a `Button`. In `CreateChildControls()` method, I add the controls to table if `!Page.IsPostBack` is true. And, table has view state enabled.

**What I want to do?**

I want the controls in the table to be present after the post back.

**What problem am I facing?**

I except the the controls, `TextBox` and `Button` to be present in the table after the post back. But it is not happening.

I feel building the whole table in every post back is little costly and enabling view state will solve this problem.

Can anyone tell if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I tried setting `EnbleViewState` property of web part. Still the same result.

Code:

```
public class TreeWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        private Table table;
        private Button clickMe;
        private TextBox content;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            BuildTable();
        }

        private void BuildTable()
        {
            table = new Table();
            clickMe = new Button();
            content = new TextBox();

            table.ID = "myTable";
            table.EnableViewState = true;

            if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                clickMe.Text = "Click Me!";
                clickMe.Click += new EventHandler(clickMe_Click);

                content.Text = "Click button to set text";
                content.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);

                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(content);

                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell);
                table.Rows.Add(tr);

                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(clickMe);

                tr = new TableRow();
                tr.Cells.Add(cell);
                table.Rows.Add(tr);

            }
            this.Controls.Add(table);
        }

        protected void clickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            content.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the view state only persists changed control state across postbacks, and not the actual controls themselves, dynamically added controls must be added to the ASP.NET Web page, on both the initial visit as well as all subsequent postbacks. For more information visit [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).